# What is a Black Box attack against Machine Learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, authentication

And is there an attack strategy that you can use to approximate the architecture of a machine learning system with the knowledge of class labels and some data points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as a "model extraction attack", and there's a line of research in the computer security literature on this problem.  For instance, you might look at the seminal paper by Papernot et al on the subject.  A little time on Google Scholar should rapidly turn up dozens of papers on the subject.